# QMail - a lot of failure notice in queue on relay open only to localhost

Tags: email

I configured a qmail server to reject messages if the recipient isn't listed in rcpthosts and I'm using tcp-env with xinetd to allow local procs to send emails to anyone adding following line to `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
tcp-env: 127.0.0.1 : setenv RELAYCLIENT
```

During tests everything seems working correctly:

```
$ telnet mydomain.com 25
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP
HELO
250 mydomain.com
MAIL FROM: someone@gmail.com
250 ok
RCPT TO: anyone@gmail.com
553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1)
```

In real life there are a lot of messages like this one in queue:

```
2744522 (1, remote)
  Envelope Sender:
  Envelope Recipient: 34c8a4690@ip-37-201-81-252.unitymediagroup.de (To Be Delivered)
  Date: 22 Apr 2014 07:38:14 -0000
  From: MAILER-DAEMON@mydomain.com
  To: 34c8a4690@ip-37-201-81-252.unitymediagroup.de
  Subject: failure notice
  Size: 18.45KB (18889 Bytes)
```

QMail should send failure notice for domains listed in rcpthosts and should reject emails for domains not listed in it without sending failure notice.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The message is a bounce message. What was the address it was originally sent to - did it contain a domain that the server actually serves?

Comment: Jenny, good question: how can I find the original message?

Comment: It will usually be a part of the bounce message. My guess is that all the bounce messages were addressed to non-existent localparts within your domain(s), since qmail doesn't verify localpart until after it's accepted the message.

Comment: I cheked some messages and you are right: original addresses contains correct domains but non-existing localpart. I understand the problem: if I stop bounces to non-existing spammer address, I stop also failure notice to people who simply misspelled real addresses. I don't see solutions to this problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'll give you an answer with some tips, as soon as I have a few minutes to spare to write it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the downsides with qmail is that as default it doesn't check the localpart of the recipient address before it accepts the message. All it does is check that the recipient domain is in its list of allowed recipient domains. (This was a not unreasonable design choice in the early 1990's. It is less so nowadays.) This means that e.g. spammers doing a dictionary spray can fill your server up by throwing a gazillion of mails to non-existent recipients. When qmail tries to deliver the messages, it will find that the localpart doesn't exist and it will generate a bounce message. And since spammers will forge the envelope sender, your server won't be able to deliver those messages, and it will fill the queue up.

The best solution is to not accept those emails in the first place. If your server can reject emails immediately on `RCPT TO:nonexistent@example.com`, then it will be the sending mailserver's job to issue the bounce and you won't get flooded with bounces.

Another solution would be to reduce the amount of time that qmail will keep trying to deliver bounce messages, so that they will be deleted earlier and thus also not fill up the queue.

And, of course, you could filter incoming spam and discard it instead of allowing it to generate bounces.

#### Rejecting unknown localparts

The only way to achieve this is to patch qmail, so that `qmail-smtpd` will check localparts. You can't do this just with configuration options, you need to actually patch and recompile and install the patched `qmail-smtpd`.

There are a few different patches that can achieve this. I can't recommend any one of them over the other - back when I was managing qmail servers we had another system acting as a proxy which did that filtering, so I never needed to use this. But you can find several patches at [netdevice.com/wmail/rcptck](http://netdevice.com/qmail/rcptck/) and [code.dogmap.org/qmail/](http://code.dogmap.org./qmail/).

#### Reducing amount of time qmail tries to deliver bounces

If this can be done for bounces only, I don't know how. But you can do it for all mails, by changing the value of `queuelifetime`. `man qmail-control` should tell you how to do it.

#### Spam filtering

There is way too much to say about spam filtering to fit into one single answer here. I'd start with considering RBL-style blackhole lists and reject connections from IP addresses listed in those. Of course, you need to choose your blackhole lists carefully, and you do risk blocking "real" mail. There's some info about spam filtering specifically for qmail at [Chris Hardie's qmail anti-spam howto](http://www.chrishardie.com/qmail-anti-spam-howto/), and there's info about various blackhole lists at [spamhaus.org](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage).

I hope this is enough for a start. I've used qmail for a couple of decades now, including running the mailsystem for an ISP with several million users - but I also have to add that if I were to set such a system up now, qmail would no longer be my first choice. It was a very good mail server when it was created, and it did a lot of things really well, but nowadays I'd probably go with postfix instead. Time and the spammers have moved on, and qmail hasn't.

Comment: Thank you very much Jenny! Probably I'll short the queue lifetime, than I'll evaluate a patch.